# Read assembly Guid without locking the DLL in an appdomain in medium trust ASP.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, reflection, appdomain

Is it possible to read the GUID from the Assembly **without** actually loading it in the current App Domain.

Normally Assembly.Load loads the DLL into the app domain. I just want to read the value.

The description of the GUID is

```
'The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib 
' if this project is exposed to COM
<Assembly: Guid("DEDDE61CD-928E-4ACD-8C25-3B8577284819")>
```

The **main** thing is I don't want to lock the file so that there are no errors 'Another process is accessing the file' error.

Comment: Is loading the assembly at all out of the question? If not, how about loading it into a different appdomain?

Comment: I want to avoid locking the file being read.

Comment: I will review the items pushed and pick an answer....

Comment: do you have any question to the suggestions made so far? Note that if you don't accept an answer before the bounty expires, you'll not be able to pick an answer anymore (but you'll not get your bounty points pack anyways). See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty for more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you load an assembly using [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h55she1h.aspx) it will load it as shadow and won't lock the file.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(bytes);
```

This is typically how tools like Reflector access assemblies without locking them.

Comment: If you use a byte array (as in the above example), the ReflectionOnlyLoad() call is not necessary.  Loading an assembly's bytes with the standard Assembly.Load() will not lock the file either.  Loading from byte array disconnects the assembly content from the file, so locking cannot occur.

Comment: That is accurate, if the only goal is to avoid locking the assembly then ReflectionOnlyLoad isn't required. However, the OPs question indicated that (s)he did not want the assembly loaded into the application domain. ReflectionOnlyLoad is the easiest way to achieve that. Using the byte[] overload does that while not locking the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Since locking is your problem, you could get what you want by using a different AppDomain with [Shadow Copy enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx) (which is the very same functionality that ASP.NET uses to keep files unlocked) when loading the files. This does not lock the original file.

Other than that, there is an overload of [Assembly.Load() which takes a byte[]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx), so that you could first load the data into memory and then load the assembly from memory. Haven't tried this though, so that I don't know it this alternative approach actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Every .NET assembly is a PE (Program Executable) file. Its internal format is documented. If has `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR` directory inside, which point to `IMAGE_COR20_HEADER` structure, which has reference to `MetaData` Section, which has `Streams` and `StreamHeaders` fields. You should find in the `StreamHeaders` the position of the stream thith the name `#GUID` and read it from `Streams` the corresponding data block. If you open with respect of IL Disassembler ildasm.exe (Windows SDK tool) a .NET DLL and its headers (see menu View and Headers) you will see the structure of steams.

You can read more information in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx and http://www.ntcore.com/files/dotnetformat.htm#MetaSection and http://www.visualcplusdotnet.com/visualcplusdotnet5a.html (from the author of "Explorer Suite" which can you download from http://ntcore.com/exsuite.php).

You can also consider the way of using IID_IMetaDataDispenser to read matadata information from the assembly. See http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/obfuscator/MyApp/MyPrivateLib.cpp.txt or "Meta" example from http://www.wheaty.net/downloads.htm